Who is the ghost in Gogol's "The Overcoat"?
While reading Gogol's "The Overcoat," I am having a rough time trying to understand who this ghost actually is. I've read several opinions on this matter, but I always find something that doesn't quite fit.
My copy has a footnote which explains that there was never a ghost, and it was the mugger all along. Let's suppose this is true and it was this person stealing the overcoats; how could it possibly be that this mugger got in the "very important person"'s carriage without him noticing? Why did the general mistook him as Akaki even though he had met Akaki himself? How could he leave the carriage as though he was a ghost? Now, even if the "ghost" weren't the mugger but the mugger's ghost, it would only answer 2 out of my 3 questions.
I have two hypotheses myself: Akaki's ghost was real but the last paragraph's ghost wasn't a ghost but the mugger itself. Second hypothesis is that Akaki's ghost did steal the overcoats in an act of revenge on the civil servants who turned him away, and he also killed the mugger, so the last paragraph's ghost is the mugger's ghost. Nevertheless, there is a problem with these two interpretations: At some point the narrator mentions that a guard managed to catch the ghost, well, how could you catch a ghost? I f he caught the "ghost" then it wasn't a ghost but a human, so it had to be the mugger, which take us back to my second paragraph.
What do you think about this?

The answers to this similar question might be helpful.

@Gareth Rees I already had a check on that post, but one answer says the ghost is the mugger while the other says the ghost is that of the mugger. They are both different, none of them have any further discussion, and they fail to answer the inquiries in my post.

Vladimir Nabokov, an expert on Russian literature, wrote several lectures on this subject. One of them is precisely on the short story The Overcoat. You can read it in the book Lectures on Russian literature. Nabokov explains that, after his dead, Akaki Akakievich's ghost haunts the city in search of the overcoat until he finally manages to appropriate that of the Important Person's who refused to help him:

      The plot of The Overcoat*  is very simple. A poor little clerk makes a great decision and order a new overcoat. The coat while in the making becomes the dream of his life. On the very first night that he wears it he is robbed of it on a dark street. He dies of grief and his ghost haunts the city. This is all in the way of a plot, but of course the real plot (as always with Gogol) lies in the style, in the inner structure of his transcendental anecdote. In order to appreciate it at its true worth one must perform a kind of mental somersault so as to get rid of conventional values in literature and follow the author along the dream road of his superhuman imagination. [...]

      The clothing process indulged by Akaki Akakievich, the making and the putting on of the cloak, is really his disrobing and his gradual reversion to the stark nakedness of his own ghost. From the beginning of the story he is in training for his supernaturally high jump—and such harmless looking details as his tiptoeing in the streets to spare his shoes or his not quite knowing whether he is in the middle of the street or in the middle of the sentence, these details gradually dissolve the clerk Akaki Akakievich so that towards the end of the story his ghost seems to be the most tangible, the most real part of his being. The account of his ghost haunting the streets of St. Petersburg in search of the cloak of which he had been robbed and finally appropriating that of a high official who had refused to help him in his misfortune—this account, which to the unsophisticated may look like an ordinary ghost story, is transformed towards the end into something for which I can find no precise epithet. It is both an apotheosis and a degringolade.
* The shinel (from chenille) of the Russian title is a deep-caped, ample-sleeved furred carrick.

You are mentioning that, at some point, the narrator says that "a guard managed to catch the ghost". In the translation into English found in the book Short story classics (Foreign) - Russian, Vol. 1 at Project Gutenberg, this is told this way:

Arrangements were made by the police to catch the corpse, alive or dead, at any cost, and punish him as an example to others, in the most severe manner. In this they nearly succeeded; for a watchman, on guard in Kirushkin Alley, caught the corpse by the collar on the very scene of his evil deeds, when attempting to pull off the frieze cloak of a retired musician. Having seized him by the collar, he summoned, with a shout, two of his comrades, whom he enjoined to hold him fast, while he himself felt for a moment in his boot, in order to draw out his snuff-box, and refresh his frozen nose. But the snuff was of a sort which even a corpse could not endure. The watchman, having closed his right nostril with his finger, had no sooner succeeded in holding half a handful up to the left than the corpse sneezed so violently that he completely filled the eyes of all three. While they raised their hands to wipe them, the dead man vanished completely, so that they positively did not know whether they had actually had him in their grip at all.

You ask: how is this possible? How could a man catch a ghost? I would say this kind of fantasy is not rare in Gogol's stories. For instance, one short story by Gogol is The Nose, which, in the wording of Nabokov in his
Gogol's biography, is

the story of an unfortunate person, whose nose went off on its own in the aspect of a man about town (as in dreams when you know that somebody is so-and-so, but are not disturbed by his looking like somebody else or like nothing at all)

In his lecture about The Overcoat, Nabokov states the following:

The absurd was Gogol's favorite muse—but when I say "the absurd," I do not mean the quaint or the comic. The absurd has as many shades and degrees as the tragic has, and moreover, in Gogol's case, it borders upon the latter.

